# What is the modern proper way to modify an android keylayout to wake the system from sleep with a key?

Tags: android, input, android-source, wakeup

There are plenty of search results explaining that you can modify your android phone to wake up due to a volume key press by modify the keylayout file.  You are to simply add WAKE or WAKE_DROPPED to the key in question.

An example to allow the volume up key to wake android:

```
# /vendor/usr/keylayouts/MyKeyboard.kl
key 115 VOLUME_UP WAKE
```

This doesn't seem to be applicable any longer.  The WAKE flag seems to be ignored.  In addition, if I use the validatekeymaps tool with WAKE_DROPPED, you can see it is not even recognized as a valid option any longer.

```
> validatekeymaps MyKeyboard.kl
Expected key flag label, got 'WAKE_DROPPED'.
```

If on the other hand, I change the key to be sent to be the POWER key, the system will wake up.

```
# /vendor/usr/keylayouts/MyKeyboard.kl
key 115 POWER
```

The system wakes up with or without the WAKE flag is it seems the POWER key has some other attribute set to tell the system to wake up.  This of course breaks the volume up functionality and is undesirable.

So my question is, what is the new proper way to set the WAKE attribute on a key?  What about WAKE_DROPPED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set the WAKE attribute on a key now. The wake flags was [removed](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/337d9d2edc262141f9b8f684e53aae5e47f0ae13).
The wake key is defined by [KeyEvent.isWakeKey](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java;l=1906?q=isWakeKey)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I added my keycode to the list of Wakeup keys in that class but no change in behavior.  The system wakes at the kernel level but then just goes back to sleep instead of waking up android.  So it seems the question still remains how to properly make Key X that is a non wakeup key behave like Key Y that is a wakeup key.

Comment: I was able to edit PhoneWindowManager.java as well.  There is a method that filters out some keys when the screen is off.  I commented the VOLUME_UP key from that list and now I can wake up the screen.  Seems like it was a lot easier the way it was before.

Comment: `private boolean isWakeKeyWhenScreenOff(int keyCode) {` is the method for anyone interested. ```* When the screen is off we ignore some keys that might otherwise typically \n* be considered wake keys.  We filter them out here. \n* \n* {@link KeyEvent#KEYCODE_POWER} is notably absent from this list because it \n* is always considered a wake key.``` is the method's comment.